# C++ ternary operator confusion

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, ternary

I have the following program, which should be simple to everyone but me!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int a, b;
b = 1;

cout << ((a = --b) ? b : (b = -99)) << '\n' << "a is " << a << '\n' << "b is " << b << endl;

b = 1;
cout << (a = --b ? b : (b = -99)) << '\n' << "a is " << a << '\n' << "b is " << b << endl;


}
```

The output of the program is:

-99

a is 0

b is -99

-99

a is -99

b is -99

On the first segment of code what I understand is that a is given the value --b, 0, so it becomes false, so b=-99 is executed. I can't understand the second segment of code, where a=--b has no parentheses, why a is given the value -99.

Comment: Setting `b` to -99 and then printing it like that should cause undefined behaviour AFAIK. Also, the order that each of the expressions being output are evaluated in is unspecified, which causes more problems. Basically, the only risky, but safe thing here would be a single `cout << ((a = --b) ? b : (b = -99)) << '\n';` if I'm right.

Comment: @chris you are right, `operator<<` does not create a sequence point, so the "a is" and "b is" parts may execute before the ternary clause, but I believe this is implementation-defined behavior, not not undefined behavior.

Comment: @bcrist, Not execute (as in be printed), but possibly be evaluated, yes. And if the one printing `a` is evaluated before `a` is assigned a value, UB, due to reading from an uninitialized variable. And if the one printing `b` is evaluated after the ternary, UB due to the lack of sequencing since `b` was last modified. The ordering of evaluation itself is unspecified, though, not implementation-defined behaviour.

Comment: @chris actually, on second thought, I believe there is no ambiguity here.  since `operator<<` has left-to-right associativity, something like `cout << a << b` is turned into `operator<<(operator<<(cout, a), b)`.  Therefore a is guaranteed to be evaluated before b, since the comma operator is triggers a sequence point

Comment: @bcrist, There's no comma operator in that expression. It isn't the operator when used for function arguments.

Comment: @chris doh, yeah I don't know why I was thinking that.  I guess I need some sleep.

Comment: @101 - You have three correct answers. Accept one of them. It's the stackoverflow way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(a = --b ? b : (b = -99))
```

here, because `=` and `?` have [the same priority](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) (15 according to the link provided) and are evaluated from right to left, it is executed as follows:

```
a = --b ? b : (b = -99)
1. --b ( =0)
2. 0?
3. 0 so not what is immediately after ? but what is after :
4. b=-99 (evaluate second expression)
5. a = -99 (assign the result of expression)
```

Comment: ; ) perfect, I am very glad that helped

Answer (score 4):

This is because `=` has the same priority as `?:` ([C++ operator priorities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)). In such case, and because they have *right-to-left* associativity, they are evaluated from right to left. So at first the expression `--b ? b : (b = -99)` is evaluated into `-99` and then it is being assigned to `a`.

Comment: I'll be sure to check the priorities again, need to get to know them better it seems. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator has right-to-left associativity, and the same precedence as assignment which means that the condition term the the second segment is interpreted to be a = ( --b ? b : (b = -99))

Comment: Thank you, parentheses do make a difference